# Pasar lista a Archivo sin los corchetes []

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo, python-3.7

```
 [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Tengo la lista anterior que quiero pasar a un archivo de texto. Al momento de pasarla al archivo se pasa con corchetes [ ], ocupo que se pase de la siguiente manera

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

el código que ocupo para pasarla al archivo es el siguiente:

```
output_file.write(str(datos)+'\n')
```

tengo la función STR porque son datos enteros y también el  '\n' porque pueden ser múltiples listas

Comment: Hola Israel! Por favor puedes poner el código **mínimo completo reproducible**. No se sabe de donde viene, ni qué es `output_file` .

Comment: `output_file.write(",".join(map(str, datos)))`

Comment: Gracias por el comentario @abulafia resolvió mi duda. Ahora investigare las funciones que utilizaste.

Comment: @IsraelSoldevillaSanchez He escrito una respuesta explicando esa solución

Answer (score 3):

Cuando usas `str(dato)` para convertir un dato en una cadena, el resultado depende del tipo de dato en cuestión. En tu caso, una lista de enteros, la conversión la realiza el tipo `list` y la forma en que se realiza dicha conversión consiste en generar una cadena que tiene el mismo apecto que la lista tendría en un código fuente Python, es decir, encerrada entre corchetes y con los elementos separados por comas.

Si esa conversión "por defecto" no te vale, puedes hacer tú la tuya propia. Para esto suele ser útil la función de las cadenas `.join()`. Esta función se usa de este modo:

```
"separador".join(lista_de_cadenas)
```

El separador es cualquier cadena que quieras, y la lista que recibe como parámetro ha de estar compuesta por cadenas. Por ejemplo:

```
"-".join(["hola", "que", "tal"])
```

Lo que hace es concatenar los elementos de la lista, separándolos por `-` en este caso, por lo que el resultado sería la cadena `"hola-que-tal"`.

En tu caso hay un problema añadido, y es que la lista que quieres convertir no es de cadenas sino de números. Por tanto necesitamos convertir cada uno de sus elementos al tipo `str` antes de poder pasarle esa lista a `.join()`.

Esto es sencillo usando `map()`. La función `map()` recibe dos parámetros, el primero ha de ser una función (o algo que pueda ser invocado) y lo segundo ha de ser un iterable (por ejemplo una lista). Lo que hace `map()` es ir invocando la función que le digas sobre cada elemento del iterable, y recolectando los resultados. Así, si haces:

```
map(str, lista)
```

Lo que hará será tomar cada elemento de la lista y hacer `str(x)` siendo `x` cada uno de los elementos. Finalmente `map()` te retorna otro iterable con los resultados. Por tanto en ese iterable retornado ya todos los elementos son de tipo string.

La solución final por tanto será:

```
output_file.write(",".join(map(str, datos)))
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la explicación

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha sido útil, recuerda aceptarla y votarla positivamente. Saluos.